# add column to data table with value from normal curve

Tags: r

I have been trying to figure out how to solve a problem in R for several hours.  Hopefully, someone can help out:

I have the following data table (only a sample shown, called xout):

```
       factorx Freq cumFreq   relative 
1    (-2,-1.9]   13      13 0.00132626 
2  (-1.9,-1.8]   18      31 0.00183636 
3  (-1.8,-1.7]   22      53 0.00224444 
4  (-1.7,-1.6]   18      71 0.00183636 
5  (-1.6,-1.5]   22      93 0.00224444 
6  (-1.5,-1.4]   31     124 0.00316262
```

I am trying to add a new column with the relative frequency from a normal curve.  I have tried to split up the column factorx into two columns called min and max so that I then use the numeric value to pass into the dnorm function.  All of my attempts at string manipulation in r have failed.  I tried to use:

```
gsub("[^/d]","",strsplit(toString(xout$factorx),",")))
```

but that failed.  I am quite new to r, so I am sure there are better ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you definitely want to use `sub`  then here is one way to do it. You can capture the group you want using `(.)` in the `regexp` pattern and then pick it up.

```
min <- as.numeric(sub("\\((.*),.*$", "\\1", xout$factorx))
> min
# [1] -2.0 -1.9 -1.8 -1.7 -1.6 -1.5

max <- as.numeric(sub(".*,(.*)\\]$", "\\1", xout$factorx))
> max
# [1] -1.9 -1.8 -1.7 -1.6 -1.5 -1.4
```

Also, you could use `strsplit`, and `substr` with `sapply` as follows:

```
# first convert to character (to use `nchar` and `substr`)
xout$factorx <- as.character(xout$factorx)
# first remove the ( and ] and then split by "," and then convert to numeric
sapply(strsplit(substr(xout$factorx, 2, nchar(xout$factorx)-1), ","), as.numeric)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,] -2.0 -1.9 -1.8 -1.7 -1.6 -1.5
[2,] -1.9 -1.8 -1.7 -1.6 -1.5 -1.4
```

you have the `min` and `max` in the rows of the matrix.

Another variation of `sub`: You could first remove the `(` and `]` using `sub` and then use `strsplit`.

```
sapply(strsplit(sub("\\((.*)\\]", "\\1", xout$factorx), ","), as.numeric)
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just do

```
data.frame(xout, newCol=c(1,2,3,4,...))
```

Of course, the vector you give could be anything.

Example: Add new column with Freq * 4:

```
data.frame(xout, FreqFour=xout[[2]]*4)
```

Resulting in

```
       factorx Freq cumFreq   relative FreqFour
1    (-2,-1.9]   13      13 0.00132626       52
2  (-1.9,-1.8]   18      31 0.00183636       72
3  (-1.8,-1.7]   22      53 0.00224444       88
4  (-1.7,-1.6]   18      71 0.00183636       72
5  (-1.6,-1.5]   22      93 0.00224444       88
6  (-1.5,-1.4]   31     124 0.00316262      124
```

Comment: I guess that is one possibility but the data frame is rather large.  I just showed a sample in my post.  I would rather avoid having to type all the possible values.  Also, I can't use a sequence because unlike the sample I showed, there are skips in the ranges of values.

Comment: You don't have to type the values? In the example I used the data from xout's second column to compute the new column. You want to compute something from your data and add it, am I right?

Comment: yes, I want the number from the factorx column, so in the examples above the first row would -2, the second -1.9, etc.